# Emission in Unity Materials Having No Effect on Nearby Static Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created a scene in ProBuilder, and marked all of these game objects as static (everything). I've also created a prefab for a "teleporter", containing a platform and a beam, which is also static (everything). The beam's material is set as emissive:

[image: Material]

I played the scene, and moved the player character (not static) toward the teleporter, so that I can see the effect. Understandably the player character is not affected, because it's not static, but neither the room nor the teleporter base is affected by the emission from the beam.

[image: Gameplay]

Is there something I'm misunderstanding or forgetting? The only possible cause I could think of is that, despite the beam being static, I do hide it until a particular objective is reached.

Here is the configuration of the mesh renderer of the beam:

[image: Mesh Renderer]

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to have worked after restarting Unity. I think it may have still been baking and I didn't notice.